# Transform reorder timestamps in dataframe - R

Tags: r

I have the following table in R:

```
S <- c("A","A","A","B","B","B","C","C","C")
TS <- c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3)
f1 <- c(10,20,30,15,25,35,17,27,37)
p <- c(100,200,300,150,250,350,170,270,370)

df <- data.frame(S, TS, f1, p)
```

So it looks like that:

| S | TS | f1 | p |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 10 | 100 |
| A | 2 | 20 | 200 |
| A | 3 | 30 | 300 |
| B | 1 | 15 | 150 |
| B | 2 | 25 | 250 |
| B | 3 | 35 | 350 |
| C | 1 | 17 | 170 |
| C | 2 | 27 | 270 |
| C | 3 | 37 | 370 |

Now I want to transform my dataframe so that I have unique values for TS (timestamps) for every row and binded my variables right to it, like this:

| TS | SA_f1 | pA | SB_f1 | pB | SC_f1 | pC |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 100 | 15 | 150 | 17 | 170 |
| 2 | 20 | 200 | 25 | 250 | 27 | 270 |
| 3 | 30 | 300 | 35 | 250 | 37 | 370 |

What is the most elegant way doing this?

Comment: your example data looks different than what you showed, hence the difference in results I believe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an error in your R code, it should be

```
TS <- rep(1:3,3)
```

anyway, a very elegant solution

```
library(reshape2)

dcast(
  melt(df,id.vars=c("S","TS")),
  TS~S+variable,
  value.var="value",
  fun.aggregate=mean
)

  TS A_f1 A_p B_f1 B_p C_f1 C_p
1  1   10 100   15 150   17 170
2  2   20 200   25 250   27 270
3  3   30 300   35 350   37 370
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Since my original df has 40k+ observations (in this example S is of the length 40k+) and 100+ variables, using your code let's my PC crash. Is there a way to handle this much data? Could be also the problem, that the respective TS rows have different lengths?

Comment: @Sphenoidale Yes, add `na.rm=T` to the `dcast` function.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done for any number of strings using the following:

```
library(tidyr)
res1 <- df %>% group_by(TS) %>% mutate(colnames = paste0("SA_f",row_number())) %>% select(-p) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = colnames, values_from = f1)

res2 <- df %>% group_by(TS) %>% mutate(colnames = paste0("p_",row_number())) %>% select(-f1) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = colnames, values_from = p)

result <- merge(res1, res2)

  S TS SA_f1 SA_f2 SA_f3 p_1 p_2 p_3
1 A  1    10    20    30 100 200 300
2 B  2    15    25    35 150 250 350
3 C  3    17    27    37 170 270 370
```

If you have 100+ variables I would include this in a `for` loop and perform the `merge` iteratively.

```
library(tidyr)

reslist <- list()
varlist <- c("f1", "p")
for(i in varlist) {
thisres <- res1 <- df %>% group_by(TS) %>% mutate(colnames = paste(i,row_number(), sep="_")) %>% select(S, TS, i, colnames) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = colnames, values_from = i)
reslist[[i]] <- thisres
}
res <- reslist[[1]]
for(i in 2:length(reslist)) {
  res <- merge(res, reslist[[i]])
}
```

---

Original, simplified answer:

You could use:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(TS) %>% summarise(SA_f1=f1[1], SB_f1=f1[2],SC_f1=f1[3], pA=p[1], pB=p[2], pC=p[3])

# A tibble: 3 x 7
     TS SA_f1 SB_f1 SC_f1    pA    pB    pC
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1    10    20    30   100   200   300
2     2    15    25    35   150   250   350
3     3    17    27    37   170   270   370
```

Differences in result come I think from the fact that the original input differs from what is shown.

Comment: This does not match OP's output.

Comment: as mentioned, I believe it is because OP's input doesn't correspond to what they showed.

Comment: @gaut thanks, I like dplyr solutions. Is there a way to do your approach with a vector of S with the length n and a vector of variables with the length k? In my original dataset, I have 40k+ observations with 2000+ unique strings of S and 100+ variables.

Comment: okay, see edits.